# MySQL server process is gone

Tags: mysql

I have a checker as cron on every minute

```
MYSQL=`/bin/pidof mysqld`
echo $MYSQL
if [ "$MYSQL" == "" ]
   then
    echo MYSQL_FAILURE  | mail -s $client": CRITICAL : MYSQL FAILURE !!!!" $mailboxes
#trying to restart it
    /etc/init.d/mysql stop
    /etc/init.d/mysql start
    echo -e "mysql:FAIL\n" >> $monitorfile
else
    echo -e "mysql:OK\n" >> $monitorfile
fi
```

And since yesterday it worked just fine. But then, I received the error message. When I checked deeper in syslog I found that on that very second, I had `mysqldump`. Can mysqldump be the reason `/bin/pidof mysqld` returned "" (no process). It is 8 core web server on Ubuntu trusty.

If this may help when I run now this here is what I get:

```
# /bin/pidof mysqld
22197 15390

after some 3min
# /bin/pidof mysqld
22353 15390
```